# Cannot install forge

Tags: software-installation, java, jar

I am used to using Windows and being able to just install .jar files. I tried installing forge by following the instructions in a video I found and I typed `java -jar forge-1.19.2-43.2.0-installer.jar` into terminal, but I got this error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2633)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2501)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2700)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2651)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1399)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1397)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1396)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1429)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName(UIManager.java:661)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.launchGui(SimpleInstaller.java:166)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:147)
```

What do I need to do to install forge?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251323/whats-the-minimum-age-to-join-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

It's probable that you installed the `headless` version of java. You need the standard version used by desktop applications.

`sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`

That will install the missing file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so` (among other things) and you should be good.

Comment: I did what you said and it opens the forge installer but in terminal it says failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" and in the installer it says there is no minecraft directory set up and won't let me install.

Comment: `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module` - do you already have minecraft installed on this box? Is it a remote server, or a local desktop?

Comment: i know that i definitely have minecraft installed because i have played it at least 4 times now (this is a brand new PC me and my dad just built)

Comment: Ok, I just downloaded forge, and ran the command. You can ignore the canberra message. Do you not get a graphical window popup titled "Mod system installer"? It's looking for a hidden folder in your home directory called `.minecraft` so does `~/.minecraft` (`~` is a shortcut for your home) exist? It should if you've played minecraft on that PC under that account.

Comment: I downloaded `forge-1.19.2-43.2.6-installer.jar` (the latest release)

Comment: in terminal i typed ~/.minecraft and it says no such file or directory but i have found the .minecraft folder and gone in it before, andthere are actually 2 .minecraft folders

Comment: and yes i do get a mod system installer window

Comment: Was this ever solved? I have yet to find a solution to this problem. Seems like forge is unable to be installed on 1.20.1-47 version of Minecraft. I do get the gui popup, I do force it to the correct folder, and I do have java installed, but it doesn't follow through and install everything that I need.